# $u, v, n$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, show that $(u-v)$ is $\perp n$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $l : Ax+By+C= 0$ be a straight line. Let $\overrightarrow{u}=u_1\overrightarrow{i}+u_2\overrightarrow{j}$ and $\overrightarrow{v}=v_1\overrightarrow{i}+v_2\overrightarrow{j}$ be  two points on $l$ with $\overrightarrow{u}-\overrightarrow{v}\neq 0$, $\overrightarrow{n}=A\overrightarrow{i}+B\overrightarrow{j}$. Show that$(\overrightarrow{u}-\overrightarrow{v}) \perp \overrightarrow{n}$.

Comment: What have you done so far? Tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: n should be on the line _l_, shouldn't it? that means it's impossible for _l_ to perpendicular to n?

Comment: It is  not on the line; it is perpendicular to the line.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but as you can see, n=Ai+Bj. It's at least parallel to _l_...?

Answer (score 0):

Show that the scalar product $(\overrightarrow{u}-\overrightarrow{v}) \cdot \overrightarrow{n}=0$.

Use that $\overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{n}= -C$ and $\overrightarrow{v} \cdot \overrightarrow{n}= -C$.

Comment: What is the second line doing?

Comment: $\overrightarrow{u}$ is on $l$, hence $Au_1+Bu_2+C=0$.